# QtQuick GeometryChanged method only works in one direction for loaded components

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm working on building a Python + QtQuick application that requires a class descending from [QQuickPaintedItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html). I'm having some trouble managing the layout and sizing of the painted item.

In particular, I have the application that looks like this

[image]

There's a set of buttons on the left, and the right side of the window is a [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) (there's a good reason for that, this is just a minimal example to demonstrate the problem).

The main qml file (`main.qml`) looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("QML Sampler")
    onClosing: main.close_application()

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            id: sideBar
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.minimumWidth: 150
            Layout.maximumWidth: 350

            Button {
                id: buttonScreen1
                text: "Button 1"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            Button {
                id: buttonScreen2
                text: "Button 2"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }

        Loader {
            id: contentAreaLoader
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 520
            Layout.minimumWidth: 300

            source: 'loaded_content.qml'
        }
    }
}
```

The loaded content file is the one that actually contains the custom class, and looks like this (`loaded_content.qml`):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import CustomPaintedItem 1.0

ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Label {
        text: "Here's a thing!"
    }

    CustomPaintedItem {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

When the window is resized, I want to be able to get the new dimensions of the QQuickPaintedItem, so in the code, I override the `QQuickPaintedItem.geometryChanged()` method. In this example, I simply print the new and old geometries.

The remaining code for all of this is below. There are three python files involved, one for main, one for the CustomPaintedItem class, and one for the main controller.

`main.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from main_controller import MainController
from custom_painted_item import CustomPaintedItem


def main():
    print('main()')

    qmlRegisterType(CustomPaintedItem, "CustomPaintedItem", 1, 0, "CustomPaintedItem")

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    main_controller = MainController()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", main_controller)
    script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    engine.load(os.path.join(script_directory, 'main.qml'))

    main_controller.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the controller, `main_controller.py` looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot


class MainController(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('ctor')

    def start(self):
        print('start')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def close_application(self):
        print('close')
```

And finally, `custom_painted_item.py`:

```
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickPaintedItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class CustomPaintedItem(QQuickPaintedItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.update)

    def paint(self, QPainter):
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.update)

    def geometryChanged(self, old_geom, new_geom):
        print('OLD: {0} x {1}'.format(old_geom.width(), old_geom.height()))
        print('NEW: {0} x {1}'.format(new_geom.width(), new_geom.height()))
```

When this code runs, I can adjust the size of the window in the y dimension (making it taller or shorter) and see that the height changes as expected:

```
OLD: 520.0 x 455.0
NEW: 520.0 x 454.0
OLD: 520.0 x 454.0
NEW: 520.0 x 453.0
```

However, when I adjust the size of the window in the x dimension (making it wider or narrower), the reported width never changes from the initial value of 520 (the window width, 720, minus the preferred sidebar width, 200). In fact, the `geometryChanged()` method never even gets called when I resize the width.

If you comment out the `Loader` component, and replace it directly with the `ColumnLayout` component, like so:

```
//        Loader {
//            id: contentAreaLoader
//            Layout.fillHeight: true
//            Layout.preferredWidth: 520
//            Layout.minimumWidth: 300

//            source: 'loaded_content.qml'
//        }

        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 520
            Layout.minimumWidth: 300

            Label {
                text: "Here's a thing!"
            }

            CustomPaintedItem {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
```

Then the `geometryChanged()` method gets called correctly for both x and y resizing. I can't tell if this is a bug, something I don't understand about the loader, or something about the layouts.

If it matters, I'm using Python 3.6 and PyQt 5.11.3.

Can anyone give me some insight on how to make this work with the loader? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layouts handle only the children, in the case that the Loader is not used: the `ColumnLayout` takes the available space since a `maximumWidth` has been established and therefore it will be the infinite (everything that can be equivalent to `Layout.fillWidth: true` ). On the other hand, the Loader that is not a Layout does not have that size policy so if you want it to occupy all the available space you must use `Layout.fillWidth: true` explicitly.

```
Loader {
    id: contentAreaLoader
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.preferredWidth: 520
    Layout.minimumWidth: 300
    Layout.fillWidth: true // <----
    source: 'loaded_content.qml'
}
```